# Getting inverse of x^2 with positive x

Tags: inverse

My goal it to get inverse of x^2 for positive x.
But the result shows always minus -Sqrt[y].
How to correct

```
u[x_] := x ^2
$Assumptions = x > 0;
Refine[InverseFunction[u][y], y \[Element] Reals]
```

I have tried this code also but is also shows -Sqrt[y].

```
Refine[x /. Solve[y == u[x], x][[1]], y \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: `Clear["Global*\`"]; u[x_] := x^2; Assuming[y > 0, x /. Solve[{u[x] == y, x > 0}, x][[1]]]`

Answer (score 2):

Using this [example](https://wolfram.com/xid/0enzab0wi-k52rc6) from the documentation as a guide:

```
if = InverseFunction[Function[x, ConditionalExpression[u[x], x>0]]]
```

> Function[x, ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[x], x >= 0]]

Check:

```
if[y]
```

> ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[y], y >= 0]

With actual numbers you get:

```
if[2.]
if[-2.]
```

> 1.41421

> Undefined